# Make a localization bot not useless

Tags: feature-request, chat, localization, chatbot

From time to time I see messages made by Localization Bot in chat, [e.g.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35258110#35258110):

> [image: links]

These messages contain links to new strings into transifex DB. But most of times when I click it right after posting - it shows nothing (i.e. strings not found). This is probably due to caching. So in the current form these messages are useless, because I can't make a translation right after bot has post a message.

Is it possible to make these links refer to actual (already uploaded) strings in transifex?

#### Possible implementation:

Before posting a link to the chat, bot should check if such link returns non-empty set of strings from transifex (perhaps via transifex API). If result is empty then link goes to a queue for next check after enough amount of time (loop this actions until API returns non-empty set, or throw it away after N attempts). I.e. bot will post a link if and only if result is not empty.

P.S. Until any improvements are made, I will be forced to add this bot to ignore list in the chat:

> [image: ignoring]

Comment: So you want SE to compensate for your impatience?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Is it impatience if the bot is saying it's available and the provided link indicates it's not?

Comment: I would suggest to change *New strings for translation* into *New strings available in 6 to 8 hours for translation:*. Much easier to implement.

Comment: @rene I'm not sure that 6-8 hours is enough. Moreover I can check bot messages immediately when they appears in the chat. But I never checked such links after 6-8 hours. I.e. in this case messages are still useless.

Comment: @alexolut [Rene was joking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/186381).