# Wrap localization bot links to unhide the strings

Tags: feature-request, chat, localization, chatbot

Currently messages from the Localization bot in chat look like this:

> [image: Bot messages]

As you can see these links are not user friendly, there is no useful information before you visit a link more than “here’s some kind of new strings”. Furthermore you need to be in the localization Team to access such strings even for read only.

I suggest to wrap transifex raw links into text through familiar syntax `[description](link)`. As a description a first N characters from the source string could be used to preventing long strings in the chat.

Implementing of this request can be helpful before [another request for improving Localization bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290749/339911) will be accepted.

Also unhiding the strings can increase the count of people involved into site localization process.